# Are there skein relations for the colored Alexander/ADO invariants?

Tags: qa.quantum-algebra

The Alexander polynomial/Conway potential can be computed as the quantum invariant associated to (a certain quotient of) $\mathcal U_q(\mathfrak{sl}_2)$ for $q = i$. More generally this works for $q = \xi = e^{\pi i / r}$ a primitive $2r$th root of unity. The $r = 2$ case gives the Alexander polynomials, while $r > 2$ are known as ADO invariants [1] or colored Alexander invariants (with $r$ the color.) Another reference is [2].

EDIT: Based on Noah's comments, I'll be a little more specific about the construction. At $q = \xi$ a $2r$th root of unity, the elements $K^r, E^r, F^r$ become central. For the ADO invariants we want representations of
$$\mathcal A =  \mathcal{U}_\xi(\mathfrak{sl}_2)/(K^r - t, E^r, F^r)$$
where $t$ is an indeterminate (which will become the variable of the Alexander polynomial.) The $r$th ADO invariant of a link is the Reshetikhin-Turaev invariant assigning each strand to an $r$-dimensional representation of $\mathcal A$. (Actually, the quantum dimensions vanish, so you need a slight generalization of the RT construction. Also, there are multiple non-isomorphic $r$-dimensional irreps, but they are very closely related.)

There are few references computing examples of these invariants. In particular, I'm curious to know if anyone's computed a skein relation for them.

1. Y. Akustu, T. Deguchi, T. Ohtsuki, *Invariants of colored links*, J. Knot Theory Ramifications1 (1992) 161184.
2. Cristina Ana-Maria Anghel, *A topological model for the coloured Alexander invariants* [arXiv:1906.04056](https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.04056)

Comment: You won’t get a simple skein theory beyond the first and maybe second.  But if you allow a lot of vertices then there’s Kauffman-Lins.

Comment: By "Kauffman-Lins" do you mean something like decomposing tensor products into direct sums of irreps and using these to get a graphical calculus? You wind up with a lot of sums over labeled vertices, but the braiding should at least act on each type of vertex in a relatively simple way.

Comment: Yes, that’s what I meant.  There’s a book that does it in full detail.  You’ll have to be careful about the usual Temperley-Lieb vs quantum sl_2 sign issue.  https://press.princeton.edu/books/paperback/9780691036403/temperley-lieb-recoupling-theory-and-invariants-of-3-manifolds-am-134

Comment: Does the recoupling theory there work directly? I'd think the fact that $K^r$ doesn't act by $1$ would mess things up, but I suppose it's not that hard to modify their theory to account for this. It's been a while since I've looked at that book.

Comment: On more thought I think I just don’t understand the construction you have in mind well enough.